# Table / Table cell / Table cell > and get 100 height challenge

Tags: css

I'm unable to solve this problem:

I want to divide a known width space  in two elements : textarea and a space for custom scrollbar. The textarea has a fix height (or dynamic if you use the vertical resizer) . 
The table / table cell without width / table-cell width 1 px does the work, almost ....

The problem is that I'm unable to give the correct height & width and position for the right div.

If I use a wrapper to use the "absolute position" approach I have the correct height but wrong positioning (you can see using chrome or similar inspect tool that the div is outside...) 
If I dont use the "absolute pos" approach I have the right width but no height... ( use the snippet, disable positioning for wrapper and inner div and see how there is a 20px space.)

I'm almost crazy with this problem... 
I want to have and automatic width & height for the right div...

Any help w. be appreciated.

```html
<div style="display: table;width: 320px; border: 1px solid red;"">
   <div style="display: table-cell;">
     <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px; max-height: 200px; resize: vertical;"></textarea>                                                              </div>
   <div style="display: table-cell; width: 1px;height: 100%;position: relative;">
        <div style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0;bottom: 0;">  
            <div style="display:block; width: 20px;">
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming I'm understanding your intention, your `div` wrapping the `textarea` is missing it's closing tag... causing the next div to be nested inside of it instead of being it's sibling.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan mmm ... right, but the snippet run is ok... By other hand, any idea?

Comment: There is a `""` at the end of first line which should be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is mainly caused by the browser default `padding` that applied to the `<textarea>`, you can simply set `box-sizing: border-box;` to it.

And remove that absolute positioned `<div>`, everything should work, updated demo below.

```css
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div, textarea {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: table; width: 320px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div style="display: table-cell;">
    <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px; max-height: 200px; resize: vertical;"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 1px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid blue;">
    placeholder
  </div>
</div>
```